# Flex 4: Nested components - Bad design?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is it bad practice/design to nest components inside components using Flex 4? Should I simply be creating components and inserting them into my main application as below, or doesn't it matter?

```
<com:MyComp1>
    <com:MyComp2>
        <com:MyComp3>
            <s:Label text="This is a test."/>
        </com:MyComp3>
    </com:MyComp2>
</com:MyComp1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MyComp1`, `MyComp2` and `MyComp3` are a **containers** then it's the recommended workflow. Custom containers in Flex 4 usually extend `SkinnableContainerBase` or `Group`. If the given code is used more than once then it's recommended to refactor it into a custom big component.

If they are not designed to contain **unknown visual elements** then it's a bad practice. Defining components inline is also known as bad practice in production code.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give any examples of unknown visual elements please?

Comment: Just any element - `<s:Label />`, `<s:Panel />`, etc.